# How to SELECT the UTC offset from a DateTimeOffset object?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone

I am currently using:

```
SELECT DATEPART(TZ, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
```

However, it returns the offset in minutes. I would like to preserve the format of '-05:00' instead of '-300'

Thank you.

Comment: No it is not mysql.

It is Microsoft SQL.

Comment: ok.. I was querying in the older version (2005) earlier and now I **really** understand your question :)

Comment: Do you want the current offset or the offset of a specific date?

Comment: The offset that the DB is currently in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to extract the exact string '-05:00' at the end of a datetimeoffset variable, you can use SQL Server string manipulation.  I do not think it is possible to do this using the built-in SQL DateTime functions.  You can use the CAST function, which I believe defaults to ISO 8601 format:

```
declare @timeStr nvarchar(50) = CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as nvarchar(50))
select right(@timeStr, 6)
```

If you want to be more explicit, you can use the CONVERT function with a format type of 126, explicitly telling SQL Server to use ISO 8601:

```
declare @timeStr nvarchar(50) = CONVERT(nvarchar(50), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), 126)
select right(@timeStr, 6)
```

Both of these approaches in my time zone return:

```
-06:00
```

For more information about CAST and CONVERT [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

In MS SQL Server you can also use

```
SELECT DATENAME(tz, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
```

which will return a nvarchar with the offset

[screenshot of the excecution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3X9Y.png)