# Get OffSet part from SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()

Tags: sql-server

Hi try to get the offset part from the result of the function SYSDATETIMEOFFSET();

For example, I need **-04:00** part of the result: 2014-03-21 11:13:14.7405400 -04:00

Is there a way the "split" a query result in MS SQL?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060535/how-to-select-the-utc-offset-from-a-datetimeoffset-object

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @timeStr NVARCHAR(50) = CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS NVARCHAR(50))
SELECT RIGHT(@timeStr, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
SELECT DATEPART (TZ, '2007-05-10  00:00:01.1234567 -05:00')
```

Comment: FYI this returns minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem I needed the offset only from a file created datetime for sending a transaction file. I used:

```
SELECT ((DATEPART (TZOFFSET, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))/60*100)
```

Comment: The math seems wrong here, this returns (hours * 100)... DATEPART returns minutes when using TZOFFSET.

Answer (score 0):

Necro answer, but its a top google result.  I wanted the hour part:

```
select FORMAT(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),'zzz')
```

Results in a result of `-06:00` for a server in CST timezone